# how to create a searchable tree on Persian text?

Tags: python, text-mining

I wanna clean my huge text data from stop-words. I already have stop-word data that is provided on the below link. It seems to me, if I have a pre-built tree on stop-words, I could save lots of time. I want to search each word of text in this pre-built tree, if the word is in the tree I delete it from the text, if not I hold it.

O(n * l) to O(n*log(l)).

[This is my stop-words](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1GRo01lSs8MjL1cUiPt_d3N7OczrGOocl)

If you have better suggestions than the pre-built tree search, I would be grateful to share it with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I've found this answer with tire tree, but I wonder if you have better option:

readindg data:

```py
#readindg stopword data
stopwords = pd.read_csv('STOPWORDS',header=None)
```

tire tree:

```py
#creating tire tree
class TrieNode: 

    # Trie node class 
    def __init__(self): 
        self.children = [None]*15000

        # isEndOfWord is True if node represent the end of the word 
        self.isEndOfWord = False

class Trie: 

    # Trie data structure class 
    def __init__(self): 
        self.root = self.getNode() 

    def getNode(self): 

        # Returns new trie node (initialized to NULLs) 
        return TrieNode() 

    def _charToIndex(self,ch): 

        # private helper function 
        # Converts key current character into index 
        # use only 'a' through 'z' and lower case 

        return ord(ch)-ord('!') 


    def insert(self,key): 

        # If not present, inserts key into trie 
        # If the key is prefix of trie node, 
        # just marks leaf node 
        pCrawl = self.root 
        length = len(key) 
        for level in range(length): 
            index = self._charToIndex(key[level]) 

            # if current character is not present 
            if not pCrawl.children[index]: 
                pCrawl.children[index] = self.getNode() 
            pCrawl = pCrawl.children[index] 

        # mark last node as leaf 
        pCrawl.isEndOfWord = True

    def search(self, key): 

        # Search key in the trie 
        # Returns true if key presents 
        # in trie, else false 
        pCrawl = self.root 
        length = len(key) 
        for level in range(length): 
            index = self._charToIndex(key[level]) 
            if not pCrawl.children[index]: 
                return False
            pCrawl = pCrawl.children[index] 

        return pCrawl != None and pCrawl.isEndOfWord
```

Example of use:

```py
# Input keys (use only 'a' through 'z' and lower case) 
keys = list(stopwords.loc[:,0])

output = ["Not present in trie", 
        "Present in trie"] 

# Trie object 
t = Trie() 

# Construct trie 
for key in keys: 
    t.insert(key) 


print("{} ---- {}".format("از",output[t.search("از")]))
```

Output:

```
از ---- Present in trie
```